# Parsing response.xml in Grails with a map

Tags: xml, unit-testing, grails, groovy

In Groovy/Grails, how do I actually assert in a unit test, the response of an XML formatted map?  The examples don't really give good documentation on the accessing map keys with XmlSlurper...

```
<map><entry key="publicKeyEncoded">Data1</entry><entry key="privateKeyEncoded">Data2</entry></map>
```

I am attempting

```
request.method = "POST"
response.format = "xml"
controller.generate()

assert response.xml.@publicKeyEncoded.text() != ""
assert response.xml.@privateKeyEncoded.text() != ""
```

Here is the map that the service generates:

```
["publicKeyEncoded": encodedPublic, "privateKeyEncoded": encodedPrivate]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `@something` with XMLSlurper what you are actually doing is extracting the value of a property called `something`.

So in your example `response.xml.@publicKeyEncoded.text()` returns nothing as there is no attribute called `publicKeyEncoded` on the root node (`xml`).

What you can do is:

```
response.xml.entry.each{ assert it.@key != ''}
```

Which will assert that all `entry` nodes on the `response` have hte `key` parameter with value.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  Also, in the closure loop, `it.text()` would return the text content of the `<entry></entry>` node, correct?

Comment: Exactly @ThomasFarvour Or it directly as the toString() method is overriden to return text()

Comment: Accepted it was useful!